# Outlook VBA Send Email Event - Passing Parameters

Tags: vba, events, outlook, handler

I've got two macros which collect data, create and send an email, then continues executing code with the sent email and the data together. The first email prepares some data, adds it to the email and sends. The second macro uses an event handler - adding an item to the sent folder - to continue executing the further code with the data and sent email.

I'm passing data between the macro in my module and the event handler in ThisOutlookSession via a global variable in my module. Even though it works, it seems like bad practice to have global variables accessible anywhere.

What is the 'best practice' way of passing parameters between a macro in a module to an event handler in ThisOutlookSession?

Comment: Why can't you just call the "do something else" macro directly?

Comment: Because I need to download the email to a local folder (among other things). Annoyingly, when an email (mailitem) is sent, it destroys itself. The only way to get it back is to use an event handler for the sent folder. This functionality seems counter intuitive, or in the very least - I should set a boolean to not do that. But alas, it is the way it is - so here I am passing data between a module and an event handler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the event handler only needs to read the data held in the module (ie not write/update it), then the module with the data should hold that data in private module-level variables (aka fields) and make the data available to read either via a Property Get or via a Function ... for example

```
Private mSomeData As String

Public Property Get SomeData() As String
    SomeData = mSomeData
End Property

Public Function GetSomeData() As String
    GetSomeData = mSomeData
End Function
```

The data can then be read (but not updated) by your event handler, for example (in this case, the data is held in MyModule)

```
Debug.Print MyModule.SomeData
Debug.Print MyModule.GetSomeData
```

Obviously, you only need the Property Get OR the Function ... I include both as examples.

Comment: So the answer seems to be use a global variable but make it readable only externally. One more question about this: to my understanding, the first macro completely finishes prior to the event handler being triggered. How is it that the global variable from the module is still in scope? How do I know that it hasn't disappeared from scope?

My own testing in this area shows that global variables from modules are not always in scope.

Comment: In the example code I gave, the variable is private (to the module), not global. The value it contains is made available to other code via the Property Get or Function ... but the other code can only read its value, not update its value. WRT your 'one more question', that really is another question entirely and can't be answered based on the context of your original question ... can I ask that you post another question ... I will say that there are various ways to save and retrieve values if variables are going out of scope ... but can't give full details in a comment alone!